# Clear Bluetooth cache on Android 7.0

Tags: android, caching, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a BLE 112 as peripheral and android and iphones phones as centrals, as the central almost never connects to the same peripherals I would like to reset the Bluetooth cache during each connection. I have added the service changed characteristic in the peripheral (service: 1801, characteristic: 2A05), and when indication is set on it, it indicates to delete the cache. On iphone it works fine, core Bluetooth does all the work. In Android sdk 19 – 23, I find the characteristic and set indication on it and it works:

```
public static UUID GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID SERVICE_CHANGED_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A05-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public static UUID STATE_DESCRIPTOR_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


final BluetoothGattCharacteristic stateCharacteristic = mGatt
                                .getService(GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE_SERVICE_UUID)
                                .getCharacteristic(SERVICE_CHANGED_UUID);
if (!mGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(stateCharacteristic, true)) {                                
    gatt.discoverServices();
    return;
}
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = stateCharacteristic.getDescriptor(Constants.STATE_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

In Android sdk 24 the indication is automatically enabled, but when I send the indication from the peripheral the communication stops. I have tried to delay sending the indication, but the communication still stops.

What have changed, how do you clear the Bluetooth cache in android sdk 24 using the service changed characteristic?

Comment: How do you know Android sdk 24 has the service changed indication automatically enabled?